# Имитация Ajax запроса в Android

Tags: ajax, json, java, android, jsoup

Добрый день. Использую библиотеку Jsoup для парсинга данных с сайта, но вот в процессе понадобилось "выполнить ajax запрос". На сайте запрос выглядит примерно так:

`$.get("test.php", { "test1": "p1", "test2": "p2", "test3": "p3" }, "json" );`

Возможно ли передать данные, как это делает ajax, в файл test.php в формате json при помощи библиотеки Jsoup? Если да, то буду благодарен за пример, если нет, то подскажите, как это сделать. В общем, в любом случае буду очень благодарен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо. Сделал так, как и задумывал, с помощью Jsoup, передав данные методом GET. Изначально не получалось, поскольку в срипте была проверка на Referer ну и, соответсвенно, cookie, а я попросту их не указал.

Answer (score 2):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой. В общем ответ такой: Через http клиенты android ajax запросы делать нельзя, только обычные http. Чтобы сделать ajax запрос нужно либо копать исходники каких-либо браузеров и писать свой велосипед, либо использовать невидимый WebView, который может это делать.

[Гуглить по словам android webview ajax request](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=2C1AFAB_enRU0538RU0538&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=android%20webview%20ajax%20request)

Или попробуйте вот так. `test.php?test1=p1&test2=p2&test3=p3`

**Обновление**

[[[[@Andreich](/users/5345/andreich)](/users/5345/andreich)](/users/5345/andreich)](/users/5345/andreich) внутри страницы выполнение javascript не получится сделать просто get запросом.

Допустим, взять страницу, у которой в определенное поле после загрузки должно вывестись число.

На OnLoaded вешается скрипт, и после загрузки он исполняется. А просто GET запрос вернет пустую страницу без числа.

---

[[[[@Andreich](/users/5345/andreich)](/users/5345/andreich)](/users/5345/andreich)](/users/5345/andreich) Хотя да. Мой ответ более общий. Автор может просто POST отправить на адрес test.php.

---

Или GET. `test.php?test1=p1&test2=p2&test3=p3`

Comment: Что? Мне всегда казалось, что это обычный пост/гет запрос.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

JSOUP парсит HTML. Ни чем другим он не занимается. В вашем случае это обычный JSON запрос.  
Как сделать запрос на сервер с JSON-объектом [найти очень просто](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android%20send%20json%20request%20to%20server).